# Ethers.js: How to send BEP20 Token Transaction

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, binance-smart-chain, bsc

I'm new to Ethers.js and I'm trying to send a transaction from a signer account (on MetaMask) to another account.

This code allows me to send 0.001 BNB through BSC normally:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const tx = await signer.sendTransaction({
  to: "0xc705.......1f",
  value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001")
});
```

What I'm looking for is a way to send another BEP-20 token (not BNB) on BSC; I really couldn't find an example of this in any docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should define the Contract object of the BEP-20 Token:

```
const token = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, tokenABI, signer);
```

then the transaction goes like this:

```
await token.transfer(addr, amount)
```

Comment: It gives error `invalid BigNumberish value (argument="value", value={ "hex": "0x8b4d", "type": "BigNumber" }`.
```
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(walletPrivate);
const connectedWallet = wallet.connect(provider);

const erc20_rw = new ethers.Contract(process.env.TOKEN_ADDRESS, require('./tokenAbi.json'), connectedWallet);

const tx = await erc20_rw.transfer(receiverAddress, ethers.parseUnits('10', 18));
```